# JQuery get radio input value and PRINT IT

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, output

I've been browsing for this for three hours now... and I found only how to GET the value from the radio input. But how do I print it?
Let's say I have this input form:

```
<form action="" method="">
<input type="radio" name="time" value="7">7
<input type="radio" name="time" value="14">14
<input type="radio" name="time" value="21">21
<input type="radio" name="time" value="28">28
</form>
```

and this script

```
var time = $('input[name=time]:radio:checked').val();
```

to get value... But how do I output it?
I've created `<p id="timeDisp"></p>` and user this: `$("#timeDisp").text(time);` but no success. So how do I do it?

Comment: Your code is fine check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/DEhsZ/1/

Comment: `:radio` in the selector doesn't serve any purpose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-selected radio button in your markup and as you are using `checked` selector, `val` method on page load returns `undefined`, you can listen to change event.

```
$(function() { // when the DOM is ready
   $('input[name=time]').change(function() { // listen to change event
      $("#timeDisp").text(this.value);
   })
})
```

Comment: Thx, and if I don't want to use this.value? Because I have more functions around. Or is it ok to use it? And I have another problem. Can I somehow use this output outside? For example if next function?